# Abnormal voltage range and frequency activity on Intel 8550U

Tags: laptop, cpu, performance, hp-pavilion, voltage

I have recently purchased a secondhand/refurbished HP laptop with i7-8550U CPU and MX 150 GPU. The first thing I noticed is that it runs unreasonably slow on games, much slower than my other i7-8550U + 620 (GPU) laptop.

I tried to figure out what is going on. Looking at the CPU-Z chart and performance tab in Task Manager, I see some very strange behaviors. The new secondhand laptop CPU operates in a much higher voltage range (0.9V - 1.35V), compared to the other laptop with the same CPU (0.7V - 0.9V). The secondhand laptop's CPU constantly has its multiplier at 30 to 40, core speed at 2500 MHz to 4000 MHz, while the other one is stable at a 10 to 13 multiplier and a 1000 to 1200 MHz core speed. All of these are idle CPU results (less than 5% usage).

What is going on with this secondhand/refurb laptop? Has it been altered? Why is the CPU constantly running at such high voltages/frequencies yet underperforming? I haven't tried undervolting it, but I don't think it would be a wise move without understanding why the CPU is not running at factory configuration in the first place. All firmware, software is up to date, including BIOS.

[image]

Comment: "Recently purchased"? Return it. If you try to fix something, you're likely to void any warranty, written or implied.

Comment: Try resetting the BIOS settings. Sounds like the power management settings have been disabled.

Comment: @Appleoddity Already tried that...

Comment: Can you run some sort of benchmark like Cinebench to get a quantitative confirmation of the differing performance?